# Why I can't add elements to HashMap (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, hashmap

I don't know what I'm doing wrong... I have the next code:

```
public class Administrator {

   private static Map<Integer, Professor> professors = new HashMap<Integer, Professor>();

   private static void addProfessor(){
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("\nADD PROFESSOR");
       System.out.print("\tId: ");
       Integer id = scanner.nextInt();
       System.out.print("\tName: ");
       String name = scanner.next();
       System.out.print("\tLast name: ");
       String lastname = scanner.next();
       System.out.print("\tInit date (AAAA/MM/DD) (including slashes): ");
       LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(scanner.next());
       if(professors.put(id, new Professor(id, name, lastname, date)) != null) {
           System.out.println("Professor added successfully.");
       } else {
           System.err.println("We can't add the professor.");
       }
   }
}
```

And when I call the ***addProfessor*** method, the error "*We can't add the professor.*" is printed. I don't know why the element is not added to the HashMap. There isn't any exception on my console, so I don't have any way to know whats wrong.

Comment: The Javadoc is your friend.  Please use it.

Answer (score 3):

When calling `Map.put()`, the previous entry for the given key in the map is returned. If `put()` returns `null`, then the entry is added, but it didn't overwrite anything.